# Is There a Way to Slowdown Running of Kingswaysoft?

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm, kingswaysoft

I'm trying to input 255 rows of data from a SQL Database to a Dynamics 365 Dataverse table. While it would normally be great that Kingswaysoft runs at one record a second, this crashes the integration which goes between Dynamics and a Legacy system.

Unfortunately, there is no way I can stop the integration from crashing short of turning it off. This is a possibility, but as this is a LIVE system currently being used by real users, I'd prefer not to.

I've tried adding a Script Component with the following code:

```
public override async void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

This was to try and limit the running to one row every 5 seconds, but it just seemed to hold up the `ClientGroup Inner Join` and `Script Component` steps before reaching the sink.

My batching/multithreading settings in the CRM Destination Source are as follows:
[image: Batching/Multithreading settings]

I've already set multithreading to off, and the batch size to one.

Is there another way I can slow this down?

EDIT: The entire data flow looks like this
[image: SSIS Dataflow]

Comment: Why is it `async` ?

Comment: I don't know, that's just the autogenerated method when I opened the script component. The line I added was `Thread.Sleep(5000)`

Comment: Throwing you an upvote because I can't solve it, yet. My first instinct was the async on the method because that isn't generated when I create a script component and it's running asynchronously so that's why the wait isn't happening. But, I did it without the async and I see the same behaviour-rows aggregate at the script task and then pop out in a batch. I dialed down max rows, buffer size, engine threads and still, batch-like behaviour. Aha, it's because it's a synchronous transformation! Recoded as an async transformation ... and it still pops them in larger batches. I'm missing something.

Comment: My experience there is on SSIS 2022, I'll have to poke around with older versions---maybe the execution engine is outsmarting me as I could have sworn this worked earlier in my career

Comment: And for those playing along at home, using a Lookup component with a cache of None and attempting to shoe horn in a `waitfor delay '00:00:01'; ` and then a hacky query to force a column to match almost works. It shows metadata, allows you to map but when you exit the editor it throws a red X on you. OLE DB Command doesn't even register the metadata.

Comment: @billinkc I just installed SSIS and Kingswaysoft yesterday, so I'd imagine I'm using the most up to date versions

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient solution, but you could try sending the requests to the CDS destination using tasks and a for each loop container instead of a single dataflow containing source and destination. That way you would at least have more control over the time between requests by sleeping thread in a script task upstream from the data flow task that contains the CDS destination. Hope this helps.